# Playframework2 : How to use transaction cross multiple database?

Tags: playframework

I'm using `Play 2.3`, I wonder if there's a way to manage cross database transaction in Play ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ORM` for that purpose, if you use `Play-Java` then check out [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) or if you use `Play-Scala` then check out [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)..

Comment: Two-phase commit/transactional monitor, which are what's required in such case, are not bound to ORM concept.